# Cross-compiled gnu for m68k, on opening core dump file gives, no core file handler recognizes the format error

Tags: gdb, coredump

Cross compiled gdb, with configure --target=m68k-linux --program-prefix=m68k- , gives error as no core file handler recognizes the format.

Details:
The core file is generated on a m68k devcie and the log is analyzed on the i686-pc-linux-gnu
GDB version - 7.6

Any clue on this subject?

> ELf format of the core file is
>   elf -a core
>   ELF Header:
>     Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 02 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>     Class:                             ELF32
>     Data:                              2's complement, big endian
>     Version:                           1 (current)
>     OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
>     ABI Version:                       0
>     Type:                              CORE (Core file)
>     Machine:                           MC68000
>     Version:                           0x1
>     Entry point address:               0x0
>     Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
>     Start of section headers:          0 (bytes into file)
>     Flags:                             0x0
>     Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
>     Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
>     Number of program headers:         10
>     Size of section headers:           0 (bytes)
>     Number of section headers:         0
>     Section header string table index: 0

There are no sections in this file.

There are no section groups in this file.

Program Headers:

```
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  NOTE           0x000174 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00570 0x00000     0
  LOAD           0x002000 0x40000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x16000 R E 0x2000
  LOAD           0x002000 0x40016000 0x00000000 0x04000 0x04000 RW  0x2000
  LOAD           0x006000 0x4001a000 0x00000000 0x132000 0x132000 R E 0x2000
  LOAD           0x138000 0x4014c000 0x00000000 0x08000 0x08000 RW  0x2000
  LOAD           0x140000 0x40154000 0x00000000 0x02000 0x02000 RW  0x2000
  LOAD           0x142000 0x80000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x02000 R E 0x2000
  LOAD           0x142000 0x80002000 0x00000000 0x02000 0x02000 RW  0x2000
  LOAD           0x144000 0x80004000 0x00000000 0x02000 0x02000 RWE 0x2000
  LOAD           0x146000 0xbfffe000 0x00000000 0x02000 0x02000 RWE 0x2000
```

There is no dynamic segment in this file.

There are no relocations in this file.

There are no unwind sections in this file.

No version information found in this file.

Notes at offset 0x00000174 with length 0x00000570:

```
  Owner         Data size       Description
  CORE          0x0000009a      NT_PRSTATUS (prstatus structure)
  CORE          0x0000007c      NT_PRPSINFO (prpsinfo structure)
  CORE          0x00000310      NT_TASKSTRUCT (task structure)
  CORE          0x00000078      NT_AUXV (auxiliary vector)
  CORE          0x0000006c      NT_FPREGSET (floating point registers)
```

p.s with older gdb version 6.3 i get an error - GDB can't read core files on this machine.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by presence of "NT_TASKSTRUCT" note, that is likely a kernel crash core. You probably need crash or similar tool.